# JSC profiler is not supported

Tags: react-native

I have some trouble to run my project on iphone device.

it works fine on simulator, but when I test on device which version is `iOS9.2`, some info output in Xcode console

```
2016-02-25 19:31:19.357 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript][RCTJSCProfiler.m:63] JSC profiler is not supported.
```

then wait a litter longer, red screen appearing that prompt me `Could not connect to development server`.

What should I do?

---

In addition, I post this question on [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6146) and be told that it's another reason cause crash.

I review my project but also have no idea, simply explain that I integrate a component which inherit `UICollectionView` written by **swift**, I'll show some main code below.

**CollectionViewManagerSwift.swift**

```
@objc(CollectionViewManagerSwift)


class CollectionViewManagerSwift : RCTViewManager, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

  let contentCellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"
  var collectionView: UICollectionView

  override init() {
    let layout = CustomCollectionViewLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: contentCellIdentifier)
    collectionView.directionalLockEnabled = true
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.collectionView = collectionView
  }

  override func view() -> UICollectionView! {
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    return self.collectionView;
  }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell : CustomCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(contentCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    // ... some code describe cell component 

    return cell
  }

}
```

**CollectionViewManagerBridge.swift**

```
#import "RCTView.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"


@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CollectionViewManagerSwift, RCTViewManager)

@end
```

I also have **CustomCollectionViewLayout.swift** and **CustomCell.swift** which be used in above code.

finally I call this component from js side.

**CollectionView.js**

```
import React from 'react-native';
var { requireNativeComponent } = React;
module.exports = requireNativeComponent('CollectionViewManagerSwift', null)
```

**index.ios.js**

```
import CollectionViewManagerSwift from './CollectionView';

// ... some code

render() {
    return (
      <CollectionViewManagerSwift style={[styles.container, {top:20}]} />
    )
}
```

and these code work fine on simulator, I could see my component from swift code which be integrated now,
I don't know what happened when I test them on iphone device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. My device changed the network gateway automatically, so my iPhone couldn't access my js bundle. Sorry for my carelessness :(

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the directory `$Project_Dir/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/`.Then delete the file `.babelrc`.Please make sure that your `React Packager` is closed before all of this.